# Is it possible to convert lightswitch application to Silverlight project(which contains UIs with xaml etc)

Tags: asp.net, silverlight-4.0, visual-studio-lightswitch

Lightswitch under the hood runs with 3 tier EF,Silverlight etc but is it possible convert project to plain silverlight project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can remove the normal LightSwitch Shell so that the entire UI is normal Silverligt controls (meaning no dynamicaly created LightSwitch controls).

See:

[Running a LightSwitch Application With A Blank Shell](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/28/Running-a-LightSwitch-Application-With-A-Blank-Shell.aspx)